# ArangoSH cannot connect arangodb

Tags: node.js, database, arangodb, arangojs

I just installed arangodb (version 3.1.17) on MacOS, and I cannot seem to make arangosh to work.

I installed arangodb through homebrew and it works properly. (I can start the service and the initial page opens if I type 127.0.0.1:8529 in a browser).

However, when I try to connect to it through the ssh client (arangosh), I am getting the following message:

```
Pretty printing values.
Could not connect to endpoint 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529', database: '_system', username: 'root'
Error message: '401: Unauthorized'
```

I already modified the configuration file, removing the #, in the hope there would be no authentication:

```
# authentication = true
```

But the error persist. I wanted to create a database and add users to it, but if I cannot manage to connect via the shell, I believe this is impossible. Plus, I cannot connect to the web page, because I don't know the initial password.

Can anyone enlighten me on this question, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf file, what endpoint do you have configured?

To start off I'd recommend you use something like:

```
endpoint = tcp://0.0.0.0:8529
```

This will allow any IP address to connect via tcp to port 8529.

When you start arangosh you can specify the server address like this:

```
arangosh --server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:8529
```

By default authentication is turned on, with the username being `root` and the password being blank.

Have a look at the [Using Authentication](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/cookbook/Administration/Authentication.html) page in the ArangoDB Documentation for more info there.

Just remember that if you change any settings in `arangod.conf` you'll need to restart your arangodb3 service to reload the settings, this includes changing endpoints or enabling/disabling authentication.

Post a reply if you're still having issues.

Comment: It worked but now I am getting the following error by Nodejs. I am using the following connection string: db = new Database('http://127.0.0.1:8529');  db.createDatabase('mydb').then(
  () => console.log('Database created'),
  err => console.error('Failed to create database:', err)
);

Comment: I'm assuming you're using arangojs? Have a look at the [Create Database Example](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs#basic-usage-example) in the documentation for arangojs. It works well!

Comment: this solution does not work for mac, 2018 with brew install arangodb. Attempting to switch from orient

Comment: Might be worth posting a new question with more information about your version and info on the particular issue you're facing, along with what you've tried.